# Value of optional type String must be unwrapped to a value type of String?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development. I'm practicing linking actions/outlets between the View and Controller. My problem is that I don't know why it shows me some errors. Could you please take a look at my code and tell me what I'm missing?

I receive the following errors:

> Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'
>
> Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
>
> Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'

Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func submitAppointmentDetails(_ sender: Any) {
    appointmentSetName.text = "Congratulations," + nameField.text + "You have now set up an appointment with us!"
}
```

A photo of what's going on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRzQW.jpg

Edit: @matt This is a different question because the thread you thought this is a duplicate of doesn't have the solution that I was seeking, but two people in this thread did give me the solution. I never would have found the solution if I just read the thread that you shared.

Comment: `nameField.text` is optional.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm trying to put the name the user has inputted in the text field through nameField.text. Even if I remove the .text and only leave nameField, it still shows errors.

Comment: @rmaddy Here's a photo: https://imgur.com/a/D8O3BzO

Comment: I think this is one of the rare scenarios where force unwrapping is totally justified. For some reason that I really don't understand, the `UITextField.text` API is imported into Swift as `String?` rather than `String`, even though it never returns `nil`.

Answer (score 27):

`nameField.text` is of type `String?` meaning it is an optional string (it may contain a `String` or `nil`). Swift doesn't allow you to concatenate optional strings. You have to unwrap the value and you basically have the Swift's proposed ways you have put in the question:

1. You can force unwrap the string `nameField.text!`. With this you tell Swift 'get the string value from that optional, I'm sure it's not `nil`', but this will crash the app if it's `nil`.
2. You can use the coalesce operator `??` this way `nameField.text ?? "<no_name>"`. This will do the following: if `nameField.text` is not `nil`, then the text will be displayed correctly; if `nameField.text` is nil, the `"<no_name>"` string will be displayed instead.

Comment: Hi! Adding ! to nameField.text did work in removing the errors, but when I ran the code, it didn't change "X" to "Congratulations, [name]. You have now set up an appointment with us!" It just changed to "C". Here is a photo: imgur.com/a/k7Eiuvd

Comment: Nevermind~ I just had to widen the label and set the lines to 0. Thank you!

Comment: Somehow your answer made me go in the right direction..Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`nameField.text` gives an optional string so to concatenate it Replace

```
appointmentSetName.text = "Congratulations," + nameField.text + "You have now set up an appointment with us!"
```

with

```
appointmentSetName.text = "Congratulations," + nameField.text! + "You have now set up an appointment with us!"
```

Comment: Ah! This did work in removing the errors, but when I ran the code, it didn't change X to "Congratulations, [name]. You have now set up an appointment with us!" It just changed to C. Here is a photo: https://imgur.com/a/k7Eiuvd

Comment: Nevermind~ I just had to widen the label and set the lines to 0. Thank you!